# how to draw multiple seaborn `distplot` in a single window?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to draw multiple seaborn `distplot` in a single window.
I know how to generate a density plot for a single list of data, as shown in my code below (`make_density` function).
However, I am not sure how to draw multiple seaborn `distplots` under a single window.
Suppose that my list `stat_list` contains 6 lists as its element, where I want to draw a single `distplot` from each of these 6 lists under `stat_list`. How can I draw the 6 `displots` under a same window, where 3 plots are displayed in each row (so that my output would have 2 rows of 3 plots)?

Thank you,

```py
# function to plot the histogram for a single list.
def make_density(stat_list, color, x_label, y_label):
    
    # Plot formatting
    plt.xlabel(x_label)
    plt.ylabel(y_label)

    # Draw the histogram and fit a density plot.
    sns.distplot(stat_list, hist = True, kde = True,
                 kde_kws = {'linewidth': 2}, color=color)
    
    # get the y-coordinates of the points of the density curve.
    dens_list = sns.distplot(stat_list, hist = False, kde = False,
             kde_kws = {'linewidth': 2}, color = color).get_lines()[0].get_data()[1].tolist()
        
    # find the maximum y-coordinates of the density curve.            
    max_dens_index = dens_list.index(max(dens_list))
    
    # find the mode of the density plot.
    mode_x = sns.distplot(stat_list, hist = False, kde = False,
             kde_kws = {'linewidth': 2}, color = color).get_lines()[0].get_data()[0].tolist()[max_dens_index]
    
    # draw a vertical line at the mode of the histogram.
    plt.axvline(mode_x, color='blue', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1.5)
    plt.text(mode_x * 1.05, 0.16, 'Mode: {:.4f}'.format(mode_x))

# `stat_list` is a list of 6 lists
# I want to draw histogram and density plot of 
# each of these 6 lists contained in `stat_list` in a single window,
# where each row containing the histograms and densities of the 3 plots
# so in my example, there would be 2 rows of 3 columns of plots (2 x 3 =6).
stat_list = [[0.3,0.5,0.7,0.3,0.5],[0.2,0.1,0.9,0.7,0.4],[0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5]
          [0.2,0.6,0.75,0.87,0.91],[0.2,0.3,0.8,0.9,0.3],[0.2,0.3,0.8,0.87,0.92]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a grid of subplots with `fig, axes = plt.subplots(...)`. Then you can provide each 'ax' of the returned 'axes' as the `ax=` parameter of `sns.distplot()`. Note that you'll need the same `ax` to set the labels, `plt.xlabel()` will only change one of the subplots.

Calling `sns.distplot` three times is not recommended.  `sns.distplot` will add more and more information to the same `ax`. Also note that you can use numpy functions such as [`argmax()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to efficiently find the maximum without the need to convert to Python lists (which are quite slow when there is a lot of data).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

# function to plot the histogram for a single list.
def make_density(stat, color, x_label, y_label, ax):
    # Draw the histogram and fit a density plot.
    sns.distplot(stat, hist=True, kde=True,
                 kde_kws={'linewidth': 2}, color=color, ax=ax)

    # get the y-coordinates of the points of the density curve.
    dens_list = ax.get_lines()[0].get_data()[1]

    # find the maximum y-coordinates of the density curve.
    max_dens_index = dens_list.argmax()

    # find the mode of the density plot.
    mode_x = ax.get_lines()[0].get_data()[0][max_dens_index]

    # draw a vertical line at the mode of the histogram.
    ax.axvline(mode_x, color='blue', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1.5)
    ax.text(mode_x * 1.05, 0.16, 'Mode: {:.4f}'.format(mode_x))

    # Plot formatting
    ax.set_xlabel(x_label)
    ax.set_ylabel(y_label)

stat_list = [[0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.5], [0.2, 0.1, 0.9, 0.7, 0.4], [0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5],
             [0.2, 0.6, 0.75, 0.87, 0.91], [0.2, 0.3, 0.8, 0.9, 0.3], [0.2, 0.3, 0.8, 0.87, 0.92]]
num_subplots = len(stat_list)
ncols = 3
nrows = (num_subplots + ncols - 1) // ncols
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=ncols, nrows=nrows, figsize=(ncols * 6, nrows * 5))
colors = plt.cm.tab10.colors
for ax, stat, color in zip(np.ravel(axes), stat_list, colors):
    make_density(stat, color, 'x_label', 'y_label', ax)
for ax in np.ravel(axes)[num_subplots:]:  # remove possible empty subplots at the end
    ax.remove()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: Instead of `distplot` also `histplot` (new in Seaborn `0.11`) could be used. This should give a nicer plot, especially when the data are few and/or discrete.

```py
sns.histplot(stat, kde=True, line_kws={'linewidth': 2}, color=color, ax=ax)
```

[image: histplot]

Comment: Seems like this would be a good place to use a seaborn FacetGrid

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, how can I fix the x and y axis of the 6 plots to be identical? like if you look at the x-axis of the 6 densities, for example, the maximum and the minimum value of the x are different....

Comment: `plt.subplots()` has an option `sharex=True` to use the same x-axis for all plots (this will only show x tick labels for the lower subplots). Similarly, `sharey=True` will share the y-axes.

Answer (score 3):

I would use seaborn's `FacetGrid` class for this.

Simple version:

```py
import seaborn
seaborn.set(style='ticks', context='paper')

axgrid = (
    seaborn.load_dataset('titanic')
        .pipe(seaborn.FacetGrid, hue='deck', col='deck', col_wrap=3, sharey=False)
        .map(seaborn.distplot, 'fare')
)
```

Or with some modifications to your function:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot
import seaborn
seaborn.set(style='ticks', context='paper')


# function to plot the histogram for a single list.
def make_density(stat, color=None, x_label=None, y_label=None, ax=None, label=None):
   
    if not ax:
        ax = pyplot.gca()
    # Draw the histogram and fit a density plot.
    seaborn.distplot(stat, hist=True, kde=True,
                     kde_kws={'linewidth': 2}, color=color, ax=ax)

    # get the y-coordinates of the points of the density curve.
    dens_list = ax.get_lines()[0].get_data()[1]

    # find the maximum y-coordinates of the density curve.
    max_dens_index = dens_list.argmax()

    # find the mode of the density plot.
    mode_x = ax.get_lines()[0].get_data()[0][max_dens_index]

    # draw a vertical line at the mode of the histogram.
    ax.axvline(mode_x, color=color, linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1.5)
    ymax = ax.get_ylim()[1]
    ax.text(mode_x * 1.1, ymax * 0.16, 'Mode: {:.4f}'.format(mode_x))

    # Plot formatting
    ax.set_xlabel(x_label)
    ax.set_ylabel(y_label)


axgrid = (
    seaborn.load_dataset('titanic')
        .pipe(seaborn.FacetGrid, hue='deck', col='deck', col_wrap=3, sharey=False)
        .map(make_density, 'fare')
)
```

[image]