# why there is extra label in my plot? (seaborn subplot)

Tags: seaborn, subplot

I am practicing to use `seaborn` and feel like it is super hard..:(

I have plotted some histograms in my subplot and I am trying to set title each of them.

after I do my job, I found there is some strange label in my figure below.

I found extra no5, no6 which I did not even set.

please let me know how to remove it...

additionally if I do some subplotting job like below,
should I always enter "n" times of similar code to put "n" graph in one plot?
ex) sns.histplot(df.no1, bins=30, kde=True, ax=axes[0][0]).set_title('no1')

```py
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 2, sharex=True, figsize=(10,6))
    fig.suptitle('Lotto Distribution')

    sns.histplot(df.no1, bins=30, kde=True, ax=axes[0][0]).set_title('no1')
    sns.histplot(df.no2, bins=30, kde=True, ax=axes[0][1]).set_title('no2')
    sns.histplot(df.no3, bins=30, kde=True, ax=axes[1][0]).set_title('no3')
    sns.histplot(df.no4, bins=30, kde=True, ax=axes[1][1]).set_title('no4')
    sns.histplot(df.no5, bins=30, kde=True, ax=axes[2][0]).set_title('no5')
    sns.histplot(df.no6, bins=30, kde=True, ax=axes[2][1]).set_title('no6')

    plt.show()
```

[image: mycode]

Output:

[image]

Comment: All subplots get the title you are setting, but also an xlabel. Seaborn sets the name of the column as xlabel. Because of `sharex=True` these aren't shown for the top 4 subplots.  You can remove those xlabels e.g. via `axes[2][0].set_xlabel('"")` and `axes[2][1].set_xlabel('"")`.

Comment: For your second question. You can write a loop:  `for ax, col in zip(axes.ravel(), ['no1',no2',...]): sns.histplot(df[col], ..., ax=ax).set_title(col)`

Comment: You should transform your data into a tidy format and use a FacetGrid instead of this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot multiple seaborn.distplot in a single figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63924125/how-to-plot-multiple-seaborn-distplot-in-a-single-figure)