# How to create boxplots by group for all dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe with 150 columns and 800 rows. Each row represents a sample, which belongs to one of 5 classes. Therefore all samples are pre-classified. I need to create 150 boxplot charts, one for each column (variable), showing the distribution of the data between the classes, for that variable.

I managed to build a code to generate the graphs, but I have to adjust by hand each of the 150 lines to indicate the location of the graph, which is a sequence [0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [1,0], [1,1], [1,2] etc., as well as the y, which could come from a list, but I don't know how to do this.

Below is an example of how it looks like. The first 9 I did by hand, but to do the other 150 would be a lot of work. It should be possible to automate this, I think, but I don't know how. Does anyone have an idea?

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 3, figsize=(18, 12))

fig.suptitle('SAPIENS BOXPLOTS')

sns.boxplot(ax=axes[0, 0], data=sapiens, x='classe', y='meanB0')
sns.boxplot(ax=axes[0, 1], data=sapiens, x='classe', y='meanB1')
sns.boxplot(ax=axes[0, 2], data=sapiens, x='classe', y='meanB2')
sns.boxplot(ax=axes[1, 0], data=sapiens, x='classe', y='meanB3')
sns.boxplot(ax=axes[1, 1], data=sapiens, x='classe', y='meanB4')
sns.boxplot(ax=axes[1, 2], data=sapiens, x='classe', y='varB0')
sns.boxplot(ax=axes[2, 0], data=sapiens, x='classe', y='varB1')
sns.boxplot(ax=axes[2, 1], data=sapiens, x='classe', y='varB2')
sns.boxplot(ax=axes[2, 2], data=sapiens, x='classe', y='varB3')
```

[image: BOXPLOTS_SAPIENS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to assign columns of `sapiens` which will be your `y` for each boxplot. Assuming that your first column is `classe` and you want to plot every column after that column, this is how you do it:

```
# get y values
y_labels = sapiens.columns[1:]
```

Next, decide on `figsize`, `nrows`, and `ncols` for `plt.figsize`. And finally start drawing using a loop.

```
import math

# calculate figure size
ncols = 3
nrows = math.ceil(len(y_labels) / 3)
figsize = (ncols * 6, nrows * 4)

# assign fig and axes
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=figsize)
fig.suptitle('SAPIENS BOXPLOTS')

# set y_labels index
y_idx = 0

# drawing plots
for axs in axes:
    for ax in axs:
        sns.boxplot(ax=ax, data=sapiens, x='classe', y=y_labels[y_idx])
        ## update y_idx
        y_idx += 1
```

Answer (score 4):

- Use [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) with `kind='box'`
- This requires converting the data from a wide to tidy (long) format using [`pandas.DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html), as shown below. [`pandas.DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) can also be used.
- Tested with `pandas v1.2.4`, `matplotlib v3.4.2`, and `seaborn v0.11.1`

## Imports & Test DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np  # for sample data

# set seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(1)

# create arrays of random sample data
cl = np.random.choice(range(1, 6), size=(100, 1))
d = np.random.random_sample(size=(100, 6))

# combine the two arrays
data = np.concatenate([cl, d], axis=1)

# create a dataframe
sapiens = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['classe', 'mB0', 'mB1', 'mB2', 'vB0', 'vB1', 'vB2'])

   classe       mB0       mB1       mB2       vB0       vB1       vB2
0     4.0  0.647749  0.353939  0.763233  0.356532  0.752788  0.881342
1     5.0  0.011669  0.498109  0.073792  0.786951  0.064067  0.355310
2     1.0  0.941837  0.379803  0.762920  0.771595  0.301360  0.772739
```

### Melt and Plot

- If there’re extra columns that don't need to be plotted, some options are:

  - use the `value_vars` parameter in `.melt()`, to specify the columns to use.

    - `value_vars=['mB0', 'mB1', 'mB2', 'vB0', 'vB1', 'vB2']`.
  - use [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [`pandas.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to select desired columns, before using `.melt`.
  - use [`pandas.DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) to remove unnecessary columns, before using `.melt`.
- For data that needs to be scaled differently, use the `sharey=False` parameter

  - `sns.catplot(..., sharey=False)`
  - However, the issue with this is that it visually obfuscates the difference between the different distributions.

    - Alternatively, try `p.set(yscale='log')` or `p.set(yscale='symlog')`, the line creating the plot.
- `p.set_xticklabels(visible=True)` should work to show xtick labels on all axes, but it's adding labels to the top and bottom, so an alternate option is provided below in the code.

```py
# convert from wide format to tidy format
sm = sapiens.melt(id_vars='classe')

   classe variable     value
0     4.0      mB0  0.647749
1     5.0      mB0  0.011669
2     1.0      mB0  0.941837
3     2.0      mB0  0.152930
4     4.0      mB0  0.467393

# plot
p = sns.catplot(kind='box', data=sm, x='classe', y='value', col='variable', col_wrap=3, height=4)

# add figure level title
p.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)
p.fig.suptitle('Sapiens', size=16)

# enable tick labels for xticks on all axes
for ax in p.axes.flat:
    ax.tick_params(labelbottom=True)
p.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Now it worked perfectly with this prameter sharey=False !

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop and use [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) to determine the axes:

```py
for i, y in enumerate(y_labels):
    sns.boxplot(ax=axes[divmod(i, n_cols)], data=sapiens, x='classe', y=y)
```